# Push notifications not working after transferring data from old iPhone to new

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I transferred data from iPhone 8 to iPhone 12 mini, using the iTunes Backup / Device to device migration. I wasn't getting push notifications for one app that I had already installed on my old iPhone. I checked the push notification settings for that app, and everything is enabled as before. I toggled the settings to on/off but it did not help. I tried to log out and log back in to that app, but that also did not fix the issue. Then I deleted and reinstalled the app, and then at the time of login, the app asked me whether I want to allow push notifications. I clicked Allow, and now notifications for that app have started working. Is it common behaviour? If not how to handle this?

*Note: We are using Braze third party service in order to send notifications to users*

Comment: Is this your app that you are developing?  Do you register the push token with your server every single time the app starts?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes I am the developer of the app. We don't register push token. every time app starts. We do it only once when we ask user to give notification permission. Also is it possible to register the push token every time app starts?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you giving me direction. You were right, I need to register the push token with your server every single time the app starts. I did it and things are working fine. Thank you again!!!

Answer (score -2):

Here's what to do:

1). On your current iPhone, tap Settings to open it.

2). Tap your name.

3). Tap iCloud.

4). Move the Messages slider to on/green.

5). On the new phone that you want to transfer the messages to, log into the same iCloud account and follow the same steps to enable Messages in iCloud.